# Как удалить все под элементы tree view

Tags: c++, winapi

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как перебрать или удалить все под элементы выделенного элемента tree view.  Код проверки на выделенность такой:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
{
    if (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == NM_DBLCLK)
    {
        TV_ITEM tvi;
        char Text[256] = "";
        memset(&tvi, 0, sizeof(tvi));

        Selected = (HTREEITEM)SendMessage(treeView, TVM_GETNEXTITEM, TVGN_CARET, (LPARAM)Selected);
        if (Selected == NULL)
        {
            MessageBox(window, "No Items in TreeView", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;
        }

        TreeView_EnsureVisible(treeView, Selected);
        SendMessage(treeView, TVM_SELECTITEM, TVGN_CARET, (LPARAM)Selected);
        tvi.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_IMAGE | TVIF_SELECTEDIMAGE | TVIF_PARAM;
        tvi.pszText = Text;
        tvi.cchTextMax = 256;
        tvi.hItem = Selected;


        if (SendMessage(treeView, TVM_GETITEM, TVGN_CARET, (LPARAM)&tvi))
        {


        }
    }

}
break;
```

Comment: `HTREEITEM item; SendMessage(_window, TVM_DELETEITEM, 0, (LPARAM)item);` Удалять вообще нужно? Оно же разворачиваться/слаживаться должно. И могу еще раз порекомендовать хранить итемы не в `lParam` а отдельно, так удобнее (мне)

Comment: Найти под элементы - [TreeView_GetParent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773872(v=vs.85).aspx), [TreeView_GetChild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773812(v=vs.85).aspx), или хранить их.

Comment: @J.Doe я храню их в lParam потому что это единственный способ, который я знаю как получить информацию о item

Comment: Так получается перебор будет выглядеть так: находим TreeView_GetChild удаляем его, опять находим опять удаляем и если больше ничего не найдет то все мы уже удалили?

Comment: Если не получать, а хранить - то грубо `struct _s { HTREEITEM h; std::string name; ... std::vector<_s> v; }; _s root, in0, in1; in0.v.push_back(in1); root.v.push_back(in0); ... tvi.lParam = &root; ...`, как бы тут ошибка, но vs компилирует это:)

Comment: честно,  я не понял) из всего этого я знаю так не скомпилирует -  tvi.lParam = &root; Там надо к LPARAM приведение типов делать =)
Насчет удаление всех дочерних элементов: Так получается перебор будет выглядеть так: находим TreeView_GetChild удаляем его, опять находим опять удаляем и если больше ничего не найдет то все мы уже удалили?

Comment: Ну так проверили бы уже работает или нет, должно работать), а хранение простое - дерево-контейнер (упрощенно будет структура с вектором) его указатель в lParam, когда идет обработка сообщений там будет весь список его детей, надо будет удалить все treeview элементы (все v.h) и очистить вектор детей (v.clear()), это если грубо.

Comment: Я кажется понял что вы имели ввиду, спасибо! Думаю подойдет!